# InvalidCastException after moving ASP.NET Core 5 application from Windows to Linux

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0, azure-linux

After moving my ASP.NET Core 5 application from Azure Windows app service to Linux app service I am getting these errors on almost all of my endpoints:

> InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'., etc.)

> SqlNullValueException

After moving back to Windows everything works fine again.

Using EF Core 5 and SQL Azure. I want to believe it is not some sort of .NET Core bug and I am simply missing some configuration because migration from Windows to Linux is quite common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it happened because app service plan was too weak. After App Service plan scale up everything works perfectly.

Comment: Just curious, was this occurring in a particular route or across the board? It's odd to me that an `InvalidCastException` would be solved by scaling up the plan.

Comment: Across the board

Comment: You have a bug in your code.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?